# Cual puede ser la falla con la actualizacion de imagen

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Tengo un formulario en php para actualizar los datos del usuario y lo hace bien pero en otro donde debo actualizar los datos de la promoción no me actualiza la foto sino que no almacena ningún valor en la base de datos en el campo de la foto. El de la parte de arriba es el usuario que me actualiza bien, pero el de la parte de abajo que es el de la promoción no me modifica la foto.

```html
if( isset($boton))
  {
 if ($boton =="Modificar Registro")
   {
      $sql="SELECT * from usuario where cod_usu='".$cod_usu."'";
     $respuesta= mysqli_query ($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
      if ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta))
      {  

           
            
            if($fot_usu!="")
          {
            $nombrefoto = $_FILES["fot_usu"]["name"];
            $ruta = $_FILES["fot_usu"]["tmp_name"]; //localizacion actual del archivo
            $destino = "../../Imagenes/Fotos/".$nombrefoto; //lugar en el que se quiere copiar
            copy($ruta, $destino);//es para realizar la copia del archivo 
          }
          else
          {
            $nombrefoto=$imagen1;
          }
            
            

        $sql="update usuario set nom_usu='$nom_usu', apel_usu='$apel_usu', area_usu='$area_usu', login='$login',fot_usu='$nombrefoto',  password='$password', niv_acc='$niv_acc', est_usu='$est_usu' where cod_usu='$cod_usu'";
        $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
       if ($result)
      {  
       ?>
        <script>
         alert ("Registro Actualizado");
         window.location="Index.php";
        </script>
```

```html
if(isset($boton))
    {
      if ($boton == "Modificar Registro")
      {
      
       
        $sql="SELECT * from promocion where cod_prom='".$cod_prom."'";
       $respuesta= mysqli_query ($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
       if ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta))
        {
              if($fot_prom!="")
              {
                $nombre = $_FILES["fot_prom"]["name"];
                $ruta = $_FILES["fot_prom"]["tmp_name"]; //localizacion actual del archivo
                $destino = "../../Imagenes/Fotos/".$nombre; //lugar en el que se quiere copiar
                copy($ruta, $destino);//es para realizar la copia del archivo 
              }
              else
                {
                  $nombre=$imagen1;
                }
          
            $sql="update promocion set nom_prom='$nom_prom', car_prom='$car_prom', obs_prom='$obs_prom', cost_prom='$cost_prom', fec_reg_prom='$fec_reg_prom', fec_cul_prom='$fec_cul_prom', fot_mtra='$nombre', est_prom='$est_prom' where cod_prom='$cod_prom'";
            $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        if ($result)
        {   
          $sql="INSERT INTO auditoria Values ('','$_SESSION[xcod_usu]','$_SESSION[xnom_usu]','$_SESSION[xarea_usu]', 'Modificar','promocion','$date','modifico la informacion a la base de datos')";
                $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);   
       ?>
       <script>
        alert ("Registro Modificado");
        document.location="Index.php";
       </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

La imagen si se sube a la carpeta? no olvidaste poner el multipart/form-data?
en donde tienes

```
$sql="update promocion set nom_prom='$nom_prom', car_prom='$car_prom', obs_prom='$obs_prom', cost_prom='$cost_prom', fec_reg_prom='$fec_reg_prom', fec_cul_prom='$fec_cul_prom', fot_mtra='$nombre', est_prom='$est_prom' where cod_prom='$cod_prom'";
```

después de esa linea pones die($sql); para verificar que datos trae tu consulta

Comment: esto me trae el die($sql) update promocion set nom_prom='Gran Rifa', car_prom='gdhdrgf', obs_prom='dhfjf', cost_prom='120', fec_reg_prom='2020-01-17', fec_cul_prom='2020-01-20', fot_mtra='', est_prom='1' where cod_prom='6'

Comment: y si coloco el multipart/form-data en el meta del form.

Comment: si te fijas en el campo de la foto en la  consulta no te esta trayendo nada , fot_mtra='', por lo tanto la variable $nombre no tiene nada